# Firebase Leaderboard - multiple boards

Tags: firebase

I just found the Firebase API and really like it. However, I was looking at the Leader board sample and was wondering if add a new column:

```
userScoreRef.setWithPriority({ name:name, score:newScore, board:myboard }, newScore);
```

can I use this to separate the return to add it to different boards? Something like:

```
if (prevScoreName === null) {
if (myBoaard == 'Board1') {     $("#leaderboardTable1").append(newScoreRow); }
if (myBoaard == 'Board2') {     $("#leaderboardTable2").append(newScoreRow); }
if (myBoaard == 'Board3') {     $("#leaderboardTable3").append(newScoreRow); }
if (myBoaard == 'Board4') {     $("#leaderboardTable4").append(newScoreRow); }
if (myBoaard == 'Board5') {     $("#leaderboardTable5").append(newScoreRow); }
}
else {
  var lowerScoreRow = htmlForPath[prevScoreName];
  lowerScoreRow.before(newScoreRow);
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this without rewriting the entire code 5 times?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should get the number of the current board and use that to add the score to different boards, like this:

```
if (prevScore === null) {
    var leaderBoardTable = "leaderboardTable" + myBoard.charAt(myBoard.length-1);
    $("#" + leaderBoardTable).append(newScoreRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That should help.